# Training a fully connected network with one hidden layer on MNIST in Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I have just gotten into Machine Learning with Tensorflow and after finishing the MNIST beginners tutorial I wanted to improve the accuracy of that simple model a bit by inserting a hidden layer. Essentially, I then decided to directly copy the network architecture from the first chapter of Micheal Nielsen's book on neural networks and deep learning (see [here](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html)).

Nielsen's code works fine for me, however, I didn't get comparable results using the following Tensorflow code. It should - if I am not mistaken - implement exactly the model Nielsen proposed:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)


def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.random_normal(shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.random_normal(shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)


x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

#hidden layer
W_fc1 = weight_variable([784, 30])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([30])
h_fc1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

#output layer
W_fc2 = weight_variable([30, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])
y = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h_fc1, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y_ - y, 2), reduction_indices=[1])) #I also tried simply tf.nn.l2_loss(y_ - y)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(3.0).minimize(loss)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

def get_accuracy():
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    return sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels})

for i in range(30):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(10)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
    print("Epoch {} accuracy: {:.2f}%".format(i+1, get_accuracy() * 100))
```

I get an accuracy of about 17% after training for 30 epochs. Using Nielsen's code, I get an accuracy of 91% after only one epoch of training.

Obviously I am missing something. I have tried to improve the accuracy and managed to get it up to about 60% by training longer, but the same network should give similar results, even though it might use different backend code. I also tried playing around with the hyper-parameters but didn't achieve any comparable results.

Do you find any flaw in my code?

Comment: 30 steps isn't many. You are only going through 300 examples then. Try running 1000 steps for your for loop. I think it will get up to 80 to 90 percent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by suharshs, it looks like your problem is caused by a misunderstanding of the term epoch. Although not rigidly the case, an epoch is usually a single iteration over the entire training dataset. If you take another look at Nielsen's code, you'll see this reflected in the SGD method. A single epoch involves iterating through the entire training_data, which is divided into mini batches. Each of your epochs is actually the size of a mini batch, only 10 samples.